# Replace commas with dots in a string column pandas without nan values

Tags: python, string, replace, nan

I have a dataset with a string column.
I'm searching to replace comma with dot, but when i use str.replace method, for some rows (maybe for integer values), it return NaN values.

```
df['code_input'] = df['code_input'].str.replace(',', '.')
```

How can i do it?

Example of my desidered dataset:

| code_input | desidered_code_output |
| --- | --- |
| 15.5C72HT | 15.5C72HT |
| 46,3C8,4HTT | 46.3C8.4HTT |
| 40 | 40 |
| ... | ... |

Example of my desidered with str.replace method:

| code_input | desidered_code_output |
| --- | --- |
| 15.5C72HT | 15.5C72HT |
| 46,3C8,4HTT | 46.3C8.4HTT |
| 40 | NaN |
| ... | ... |

Comment: Can you try `df['code_input'].astype(str).str.replace(',', '.')` ?

Comment: .., or use `df['code_input'] = df['code_input'].str.replace(',', '.', regex=True)`.